# Line under one column

Tags: tables, rules

Simple question that I couldn't find an answer to anywhere: I am using `\cline` to create discontinued lines in my tables. Sometimes I want to have a line just spanning over one column rather than multiple columns. `\cline` only works for more than one column. What is the alternative?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that you have received answers to your questions, but you haven't up-voted or accepted any of them (up-voting and accepting are two different actions). Please consider revisiting your answers, up-voting good answers and accepting the one you consider best solved your problems. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 15):

`\cline{1-1}`, `\cline{2-2}` and so on to underline only first, second and so on column.